# How to mock external function call in jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is my Node.js module to test (userdata.js file):

```
const myService = require('./my-service')

class UserData {
  getData(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      myService.getUserData(query)
        .then((userdata) => {
          myService.getManagerData(userdata)
            .then((managerdata) => {
              resolve(managerdata)
            })
        })
    })
  }
}
module.exports = UserData
```

and test file:

```
const UserData = require('/.userdata')
test('UserData.getData', () => {
  expect(UserData.getData('John Smith')).toBe('John\' manager');
});
```

I want to mock myService.getUserData and/or myService.getManagerData functions call that I'm not directly declare in test file.. How do I mock them properly to return some dummy result?

Comment: Did you try `jest.mock()` ?

Comment: I did. But the question is how to properly do that.. If I import myService in test file and mock it there - will it really work in userData call?

Comment: how do I mock myService.getUserData in test file that is not imported myService. And if import and mock - will it work since it's not mocked in UserData module itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to make stub for `myService.getUserData` and `myService. getManagerData` methods.

E.g.

`userData.js`:

```js
const myService = require('./myService');

class UserData {
  getData(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      myService.getUserData(query).then((userdata) => {
        myService.getManagerData(userdata).then((managerdata) => {
          resolve(managerdata);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = UserData;
```

`myService.js`:

```js
const myService = {
  getUserData(query) {
    return 'real user data';
  },
  getManagerData(userdata) {
    return 'real manager data';
  },
};

module.exports = myService;
```

`userData.test.js`:

```js
const UserData = require('./userData');
const myService = require('./myService');

describe('61784452', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(myService, 'getUserData').mockResolvedValueOnce('fake user data');
    jest.spyOn(myService, 'getManagerData').mockResolvedValueOnce('fake manager data');
    const userData = new UserData();
    const actual = await userData.getData('query');
    expect(actual).toEqual('fake manager data');
    expect(myService.getUserData).toBeCalledWith('query');
    expect(myService.getManagerData).toBeCalledWith('fake user data');
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61784452/userData.test.js (12.908s)
  61784452
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |   84.62 |      100 |   71.43 |   84.62 |                   
 myService.js |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3-6               
 userData.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.99s
```